# Multiple Or Conditions in Regex

Tags: regex, expression

Lets say I have messy data pattern:

- TRND-0LL2134.SV
- TRN_RTXDFT.SV
- TRND_ZRSFTFF.SV
- DR3345.SV

I am trying to use regex to filter on prefixes with "-" or "_", and those without.

Desired output

```
column1     column2     column3
=========== =========== ===========
TRND        -           0LL2134.SV
TRN         _           RTXDFT.SV
TRND        _           ZRSFTFF.SV
<blank>     <blank>     DR3345.SV
```

So far I used

```
\-|\_
```

to filter on prefixes with "-" or "*" but have a challenge filtering on strings that do not have a prefix with either "-" or "*"

Comment: What is the environment? Python Pandas? R? Can there be any chars before `_` or `-`, or just alphanumeric?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `[-_]?` to match the optional separator.

Use a non-greedy quantifier for the first word so that if there's no separator, it will be blank and the word will be associated with column 3.

```
^([A-Z0-9]*?)([-_]?)([A-Z0-9]+\.SV)$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/LmVeCQ/1)

Answer (score 0):

Use a `?` to make a group optional

```
^(([A-Z]+)[-_])?(\w+.SV)$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uNNis6/2)

If you want to match exactly the characters sequence `TRN(D)` than:

```
^((TRND?)[-_])?(\w+.SV)$
```

Answer (score 0):

Your matching expression should contain 3 groups for data to be fed into each of the columns of your output and be anchored at the beginning of your test strings.

Specifically, try ...

```
/^((.*)([_-])(.*))|^([^_-]+)$/
```

Capture groups #2,3,4 will contain the data to go into your columns 1,2,3, resp.; in case there is none of the separating characters in the test string, the content of column 3 will be in capture group #5

The way you've described your problem, this pattern will *always* match - the only difference is in how the test string is distributed into the column slots. If valid test strings need to end on `.SV`, use

```
/^((.*)([_-])(.*[.]SV))$|^([^_-]+[.]SV)$/
```

As you haven't indicated in which programming environment you are operating this answer can not specifiy how to employ the regex.

Online examples are available on Regex101.com for [Variant 1](https://regex101.com/r/UII8yT/2) and [Variant 2](https://regex101.com/r/bwFHr8/1)